# Sencha Touch simple model validation matcher

Tags: javascript, regex, model, sencha-touch

I am trying to validate a simple textfield that should accept
either:

the numbers 0-100
*OR* 
 the letters A-F

To clarify, it is for a teacher grading assignments, so only the scores of 0-100 and A-F are accepted (no special/non-alphanumeric characters etc).

I just can't seem to wrap my head around reg exp and the Sencha Touch matcher. I have seen the other posts but they are not quite applicable to my question. Thanks.

My model:

```
    Ext.define('App.model.EnterGradesModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    alias: 'model.User',

    config: {
        fields: [
            {
                grade: 'grade'
            }
        ],
        validations: [
            {
                type: 'format',
                field: 'grade',
                matcher:    //This is where I need the help ----- ,
                message: 'Grade should be 0-100 or A-F'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Handler in my view:

```
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            width: 100,
            text: "Save",
            id: "saveMyGradeButton",
            action: 'saveMyGrade',
            handler : function() {
                var model = Ext.create('App.model.EnterGradesModel', this.up('formpanel').getValues());
                var errors = model.validate();
                console.log(model);

                if (errors.isValid()){
                    // Validation successful - fire grade event in controller
                    this.fireEvent('saveMyGrade', this);

                } else {
                    // Validation failed
                    var data="";
                    console.log(data);
                    errors.each(function (item, index, length) {
                        data = data + '| '+ item.getField() + ' - ' + item.getMessage() + ' |';
                    });
                    Ext.Msg.alert("oops.", data);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression will validate one of the following conditions is true

- value is 100
- value is a double digit number 10-99
- value is any single digit number 0-9
- value is letters A thru F

`^(?:100|[1-9]\d|\d|[A-F])$`

[image]

Comment: Looks great but it still fails validation

Comment: On the matcher line are you making it look like: `matcher: /^(?:100|[1-9]\d|\d|[A-F])$/,` where the regular expression is surrounded with slashes? I ask because the expression does work as expected, http://www.rubular.com/r/VZ3Aztrobn.

Comment: I ended up using a match statement like the following:  if (!grade.match(alphNum)){  ..show error..}  instead of the Sencha touch validation system.